# Storing Sql Queries in Json file

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am messing around with some python and snowflake. I am using a JSON file to store my connection info like this:

```
{
  "snowflake_config": {
    "user":      "automation",
    "password":  "************",
    "account":   "someaccounthere",
    "warehouse": "somewarehousehere",
    "database":  "somedatabasehere",
    "schema":    "someschemahere"
  }
}
```

But I have a few hundred SQL queries that I would like to run that will accept arguments.  Can I store them in a json file as well? Or does snowflake using execute_stream really require the file to be static?  I was hoping I could do something like this (pseudo code):

```
{
 "snowflake_queries": {
  "sql1": "GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA %s<this is argparse1> to role <argparse2>",
  "sql2": "GRANT SELECT ON ALL VIEWS IN SCHEMA %s<this is argparse1> to role <argparse2>"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `execute_stream()` can handle parameters, but why do you want to use it?
`execute_stream()` is for verbatim execution of a script like `Run All Queries` in a Snowflake Web GUI worksheet. That means you can use eg. SQL variables as parameters in the script, but you can't use parameters from somewhere else unless you prepend eg. `SET myvar = value;` to the script.

I suggest you use just `execute()` or perhaps `executemany()`, which both take parameters.
In general, they work like this with a tuple of parameters:

```py
snowflake_queries = {
  "q1": "GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA IDENTIFIER(:1) to role IDENTIFIER(:2)",
  "q2": "GRANT SELECT ON ALL VIEWS IN SCHEMA IDENTIFIER(:1) to role IDENTIFIER(:2)"
}

for key, sqlText in snowflake_queries.items():
  my_cursor.execute(sqlText, ((SomeSchema, SomeRole)))
```

There are some commands and functions that have parts that cannot be substituted by parameters *yet*.  Those are (Dec 2019) import/export command parameters and notably time travel eg. `AT(OFFSET => n)` and the `GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => n)` function.
Then you have to do string formatting yourself in the `sqlText`.

In other commands it is possible to use non-literal parameters with the `IDENTIFIER()` wrapper, eg. schema/table and user/role names.  I've used this in the code above.

**A final word**:
The case above (an administrative helper script) is a perfect candidate for a [Stored Procedure](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures.html).

Comment: I was looking at args because I would like args passed to the query command line like ```python some_python.py --firstarg SomeSchema --secondarg SomeRole``` to then be passed like what I mentioned above to the json. I guess I can use execute to just iterate over the queries in json. The parameters to the queries should come from the args passed.

Comment: Sure.  Like the following: `for key, sqltext in snowflake_queries.items(): my_cursor.execute(sqltext, ((SomeSchema, SomeRole)))`